# what exactly does not setting Idle Time in MongoClientOptions do?

Tags: java, mongodb, connection-pooling

I am working on mongodb connection pooling & I came across this option we can set in mongo client : "MaxConnectionIdleTime".

It basically means that connection will die after this time when sitting idle.

**The default value is zero & it's stated that in case of zero, there's no limit.
Does it mean that once a connection has been created it won't die at all & will be kept in pool forever ?**

[image: Code snippet from mongo library]

Assuming there's space for new connections to be created in the pool. like min connections=10 & max connections =1000. & also, the max connection time isn't set.

If you can suggest a method to test it out on my own, that'll be really helpful too.

Please let me know if there's any way I can improve the question.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"Die" is a sloppy term and it is not clear what you mean by it.

If no idle time is set, the connection will not be proactively *closed* by the driver upon that idle time elapsing. That's all.

Connections may be *closed* by the driver in the following other circumstances:

- It experiences a network error or a timeout.
- Another connection to the server that this connection is associated with experiences a network error, causing the server to be  marked unusable by the driver.

A connection may *become unusable* because of a network error. The connection may *be unusable* without the driver knowing about it. The driver often detects unusability of a connection when trying to use it (i.e. write or read something) which means a connection may be *unusable* (one might say *dead*) while the driver thinks it is perfectly fine, for a long time.